# Is there a way to search for the month inputted into a timedate object and link it to the matching key in dictionary with same month

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, timedate

Have a fairly simple program with a take a input for birthday which gives a day and month for birthday as a timedate object for example 19 May and have a dictionary with 12 keys aka January to December looking for a way to use a dictionary method to grab the value of the month inputted as a string and then converted to a timedate object.

```
#input birthday string
birthday = str(input("Please enter you birthday in the following format: dd/mm/yyyy."))
birthdate = datetime.strptime(birthday, "%d/%m/%Y") #formatting of input
birthdate2 = datetime.strftime(birthdate, "%d %B") #day and month object
print("Your birthday is on", birthdate2) #print the day and month object
    
#dictionary
famousBirthdays = {
    "January": "Mozart",
    "February": "Charles Darwin",
    "March": "Albert Einstein",
    "April": "Elizabeth II",
    "May": "Linnaeus",
    "June": "Josephine Baker",
    "July": "Frida Kahlo",
    "August": "Barack Obama",
    "September": "Elizabeth I",
    "October": "Gandhi",
    "November": "Marie Curie",
    "December": "Emily Dickinson"
    }
```

Haven't tried much so far as very new to python and struggling to come up with any ideas best idea i came up with was isolate the month in a new `timedate` object and write a statement to compare the two based on input and pull the corresponding value in the `dictionary` but not sure where to start

Comment: Hi Philipp, welcome to Stackoverflow. It is fairly simple, you can use numbers instead of full month name as keys for dictionary (eg. `{1:"Mozart", 2:"Charles Darwin"} ...`) and then use `birthdate.month` to get month from `datetime` object and get the famous person like `famous_person = dictionary[birthdate.month]`

Comment: Or if that is not the solution, use `calendar` library like shown here: https://pynative.com/python-get-month-name-from-number/

Comment: feel free to post it as answer so someone in future will see this incase they run into similar issues

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping in the comments thanks, Bijay Regmi. Found a solution by adding an extra line to the timedate bit, a simpler way to handle it would prob be using number dates to simply things. Requirements constrained me, but an easy fix nonetheless is much appreciated.

```py
# added between birthdate2 and print
birthmonth = datetime.strftime(birthdate, "%B") 

# added at end after the dictionary
famous_person = famousBirthdays[birthmonth]  
print(famous_person)
```